# Laravel - I have a User model that has different roles. How to make a relationship between users with certain roles?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a User model and a Role model in Laravel 5.2. In my roles I have student and teacher. Each student has many teachers and vice versa. How can I link them?

Comment: The subject is pretty well covered in laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

Comment: But I don't have 2 models. I have just one User that has different roles. I need users to store users according to a certain role.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You need to create the three tables `roles` - `users` - `role_user` see below:

Roles Table:

```
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
    });
```

Then 
users Table

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

user_role Table

```
Schema::create('user_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('role_id')
        ->references('id')->on('roles');
});
```

Create Role model:

```
class Role extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'roles';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_role');
    }
}
```

Afterwards add the roles relationship to the user model

```
class User extends Authenticatable {

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_role');
    }
}
```

To give a user a role,

```
$user = User::findOrFail(1); //lets say for user 1
$user->roles()>attach(Role::where('name', 'Teacher')->first());
```

Comment: That is not what I am asking I have already done that

Comment: Check the last example of attach()

Comment: Again, that is not what I am asking. I need users with role student to have  a many to many relationship with users with role teacher.

Comment: Can you please read the solution again and again and again...

Comment: $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('role_id')
        ->references('id')->on('roles');
Is this what makes the connection between 2 Users with different roles?

Comment: Yes here is the many to many relationship

Comment: I will try it out. Thanks a lot and sorry for not understanding from the first time.